# Would obtaining a residence permit in country B be an obstacle to naturalizing in country A?

Tags: citizenship

I am a foreign citizen with ILR (permanent residence) in the United Kingdom. I intend to apply for British citizenship as soon as I fulfil the 5 year residency requirement in about one years time.

I have a permanent address, income and provable social ties to the UK. I also spend around 10-11 months out of a year in the UK, while the rest is spent in other countries for business purposes mainly. I have nothing on my record that could disqualify me from being able to naturalize.

To simplify some business processes overseas, I have been advised that it is beneficial for me to obtain a temporary residence permit overseas.

Given that I continue to fulfil all the requirements to be eligible for naturalization, is it at all possible that having a foreign residence permit in my passport going to be an obstacle to becoming a British citizen?

Comment: Hi Geoff, how long would this temperoary residence permit last? I doubt it would make a big difference, though it might improve the context of your question.